# Entity Framework - Using Navigation Properties over Joins

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm working with Entity Framework on a legacy database with no relationships. Our queries are now written as Linq Joins.

**Are there advantages (and maybe disadvantages) to adding associations in the model and writing our queries with Navigation Properties?** I had no luck so far finding a straightforward answer to this question and want to know if it's worth the effort.

I believe there is no benefit performance wise if the query generated by the Navigation Properties is similar to the Join query.

I listed what I believe are the pros and cons of **Navigation Properties compared to Joins**:

**Pro**

- Queries are a lot shorter and more readable because the mappings of the keys are hidden
- Object relationships are automatically provided
- Results are hierarchical and not flattened

**Con**

- Creating the query with Include-statements can take longer (see 8.2.2 in the very interesting link [Performance Considerations for Entity Framework 4, 5, and 6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx))

Comment: I'm not sure how you have your DAL setup but if the results of the DAL are NOT `IQueryable`, then with navigation properties you could control eager/lazy loading at the DAL levels instead of having other developers mistakingly lazy load additional data.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you've answered your question. Of course, queries using navigation properties are much more convenient, than queries with `join`s.

Concerning `Include`s - overusing of `Include` is mostly analogue of overusing of `join`, because `Include` is at least `join` and, optionally, something else. Do not write queries with tens of `Include` calls, and there won't be performance hit.